# Avoid going to the previous page after logging out of the website in a spring mvc application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have made a spring M V C application in which i have provided a log out feature.
But whenever i log out of the system and press the back key i am redirected to the previous page which should not happen in ideal case on logging out.

please help me on how to avoid this.

My controller part for log out is as under:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/logout",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) 
{   
         session=request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
        {
        l.info(""+session.getAttribute("username"));
        session.invalidate();   
        }
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0    
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1  
        response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
        String redirect="jsp/index";
        return new ModelAndView(redirect);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried it and it is working fine for me.
Add this handler to your spring security file

```
<logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"
        invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
<beans:bean id="logoutSuccessHandler"
    class="com.neosyn.security.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

define class logout handler

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
    setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
    super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

}

Comment: thanks yes this is working fine.....

also i want to know that is there any way other than using spring security to do the same???